# Typescript: making interface parameters optional when passing to a function

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a typescript function, that accepts an options object as a parameter. I have an interface that defines the options. I also have a constant that contains default values for every option. It looks something like this:

```js
interface Options {
  viewportHeight: number
  viewportWidth: number
  // ...
}

const defaults: Options = {
  viewportHeight: 600,
  viewportWidth: 600,
// ...
}

function createGenerator(options: Options) {
  options = { ...defaults, ...options }

  return function generate() {
    // Simplfied
    return {
      value: Math.min(options.viewportWidth, options.viewportHeight),
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the following: if I leave all properties of the `Options` interface requires, then I can't do something like `createGenerator({ viewportWidth: 50 })` to set only the options I need and leave the rest by default

If I do make them optional, then all options like `options.viewportWidth` have the type of `number | undefined` which causes an error `Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'` when I'm trying to use them.

I could define two interfaces like `Options` and `FilledOptions`, but that's not DRY. Is there some nice way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Partial` to make all members of a type optional. You will however need to use a different variable for the final parameters, as TS will just take the assigned type and complain that properties may be `undefined`

```
interface Options {
  viewportHeight: number
  viewportWidth: number
  // ...
}

const defaults: Options = {
  viewportHeight: 600,
  viewportWidth: 600,
// ...
}

function createGenerator(_options: Partial<Options>) {
  const options = { ...defaults, ..._options }

  return function generate() {
    // Simplfied
    return {
      value: Math.min(options.viewportWidth, options.viewportHeight),
    }
  }
}

createGenerator({ viewportWidth: 50 })
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMsgG7AQDu62UYAEhMAOYAWYAXMiAK4BbAEbRSFKrXpgA6sAAmYdj37DRZAPTrkAOl3EAvsWIJceMMjkR4fADZg8PDFlPIAvETGUadBszaceADYABmCAGk8JHxl5RSDQiM0dPUNiGD4QBGcQZAQoCDhIAHEIEGhC+gAKAH1sTBx8HgAFOAZgOBsAHicGvAA+AEoPMhN8czrsgndCZO1Lazs8MNna+pdUsnywPigc9Mzs5FZS8shKoZIyDS0AZWABdBsYKjkxTYht3eGrsnIOvggPAAsoV2NoBKBKhNetovJIGLIFOxltDTLColI-BwwAMIj9DGRDKk8gViicoBUoJUZnDooi4sgAKzBZD6AZAA)